# How to chain filters with rsyslog 5.8

Tags: rsyslog

I'm attempting to create an rsyslogd filter that forwards syslog messages from a remote host that are above a certain severity level. I'm able to do it on a different server that has rsyslogd v8.24. But I'm stuck trying to do it with the old rsyslogd v5.8 syntax.

The only filter I've had success with is `app-name` and currently my rules are:

```
:app-name, isequal, "app1" @192.168.100.200:514 
:app-name, isequal, "app2" @192.168.100.200:514
```

How can I add a severity level filter so that only messages that match the app names AND are above a certain level get forwarded?

With rsyslogd v8.24 my filter is as below. It would be even better if there was a way to replicate that in v5.8.

```
if $fromhost-ip == "192.168.0.50" and $syslogseverity <= 4 then @192.168.200.200:514
```

Comment: According to the 5.10.2 [doc](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v5-stable/configuration/index.html) the v8 syntax you are using was already partially available (see under RainerScript). Did you try it in your 5.8? Use debug option `-dn` to run in the foreground and get config error messages.

Comment: Yes I did try the new syntax with v5.8 and I was never able to get a rule using it to trigger. Thanks for the `-dn` tip, very useful. When using it with v5.8 nothing shows in the logs for the new syntax, With v8.24 there are log messages about the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I download and built the 5.8 sources, and did some testing, and to cut a long story short, all you need to do is change from using double-quotes to single-quotes for your string constants in RainerScript. I.e. try

```
if $fromhost-ip=='192.168.0.50' and $syslogseverity<=4 then ...
```

---

For other readers who may need to do a similar build,
I downloaded the [5.8 sources](https://www.rsyslog.com/downloads/download-other/) and configured them with debug and imfile (to use for input):

```
./configure --enable-debug --enable-diagtools --enable-imfile
make
```

Since I didn't want to install the files to `/usr/local`, I set DESTDIR to create an installation tree under the build directory.

```
make install DESTDIR=$PWD/x
```

The rsyslogd binary is then in `x/usr/local/sbin/`.
The arguments to use for a standalone test config need `-u2` to not do a `chdir("/")`, and `-c5` forces the parsing to stay in version 5 syntax, so run with:

```
rsyslogd -c5 -u2 -i /tmp/pidfile -f my.conf
```

to which you need to add `-M$PWD/x/usr/local/lib/` to find the modules.
You can do a config file syntax check with `-N1`, and run with debug with `-dn`.

Comment: I can confirm you are exactly right. Changing from double to single quotes got the filter working with v5.8. Thanks for your dedication to the cause!